# AVAudioPlayer setting a pre-defined stop point on the audio file without input from user

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I've been struggling trying to set specific points for start and stop an audio file. I downloaded Apple's sample code avTouchController. So far I've been successful in changing currentTime to start the playback. I have tried several ways to create a stopPlayer method. I created it and have no issues. However, so far the player doesn't stop.
ANy clues?
Here's the method I've implemented

```
(void)stopPlaybackForPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)p

{ if (p.playing)

    if (p.currentTime == 6 )
    {
        [p stop];
        [self updateViewForPlayerState:p];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling this method? Have you put a breakpoint into it to see what is happening?

As far as I can see, the only way to do this with an `AVAudioPlayer` is to set an `NSTimer` which will call that method for you when it fires. Having an equality check for the `currentTime` is probably not a good idea there because it the time might not be exactly what you expect and can be slightly smaller or larger. If you've set a timer for roughly the time you want it to stop, having the method execute and stop the player unconditionally should be fine.

Have you considered using an [`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html) instead? You can achieve this more easily by simply using the `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:` method to accomplish this pretty easily.